# Swagger Json no Postman não colocar a URL da API

Tags: c#, .net, api, swagger

Estou utilizando a biblioteca Swagger no .NET CORE em uma Web API para gerar a documentação, segue abaixo com está o meu startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddTransient<Context>();

        // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "Basic API",
                Description = "A simple example ASP.NET Core Web API",

            });

            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Example Api v1");
            c.RoutePrefix = "docs";
        });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Quando pego o JSON dele pera url `https://localhost:44397/swagger/v1/swagger.json`, ele me gera o JSON puro e consigo importar no POSTMAN, só que ele fica sem a URL base nas requests, conforme print abaixo.

Alguém pode me ajudar para aparecer a URL base quando importo para o POSTMAN? Falta configurar algo no Startup?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando você usa o SWAGGER normalmente ele te dá a opção para realizar as chamadas via navegador, dessa maneira não necessita do POSTMAN. Mas como cada caso é um caso, se você quer acessar sua API pelo postman vai acessar pelo link: localhost://XXXX/api/controller/methodName/params (caso aja).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o IDocumentFilter para realizar essa alteração:

```
  /// <summary>
/// Filtro Swagger
/// </summary>
public class CustomDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        swaggerDoc.BasePath = "localhost:5001";
        swaggerDoc.Schemes = new List<string> { "https" };
    }
}
```

E injetar no Startup:

```
      services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "Basic API",
                Description = "A simple example ASP.NET Core Web API", 

            });
            c.DocumentFilter<CustomDocumentFilter>();

            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas é só um exemplo, se realmente precisar fazer isso, faça dinamicamente por tipo de ambiente.